# Can different Topologies in LocalCluster have streams and bolts with same name in apache-storm

Tags: java, apache, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I need to run multiple storm projects in LocalCluster mode.

```
ProjectA->TopologyA->Spout1(listing to some stream X )->Bolt1->Bolt2
ProjectB->TopologyB->Spout1(listing to some stream Y )->Bolt1->Bolt2
ProjectC->TopologyC->Spout1(listing to some stream Z )->Bolt1->Bolt2
```

When I run projects A,B and C somehow streams are read by spouts of other projects.
What could be the reason for this.

PS:Fairly new to Storm, have tried to figure out from documentation but could not figure out anything concrete.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean when you say that e.g. Spout1 is listening to stream X? What kind of spout is it, and what is the stream?

Comment: My question is generic, say the stream is mails from gmail using pop3. Spout is Generic.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think first you should figure out whether the spout streams are overlapping. That is, you should put a log in your Spout1 that logs when you emit, and try running all the topologies and verify whether the TopologyA and TopologyB Spout1 instance are reading the same messages.

Also are you starting one or 3 LocalClusters to run these topologies? Try starting a single LocalCluster that you submit all the topologies to, I'm not sure LocalCluster is designed to have multiple instances running.

Comment: "spout streams are overlapping" - Yes they are overlapping
"are you starting one or 3 LocalClusters " - 3 seperate localclusters
"LocalCluster is designed to have multiple instances running" - Will check on this and share observation